# Authenticating a Azure Mobile App Back End through Google Play

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

I have a mobile app that has an Azure back end.  It works the way it is.  My authentication code is as follows:

```
client = new MobileServiceClient(Settings.ServiceURI);

var user = await client.LoginAsync(this,
                    MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, "appname");
```

The problem with this is that it literally takes you to the ServiceURI of my App before it redirects you to Google for authentication.  Even in the Google authentication, it displays the ServiceURI as that to which you are logging in.  Is there a better way to do this so that you just see the Google login page with no information displayed concerning the ServiceURI?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure#using-an-azure-mobile-apps-instance) to login google.

Comment: @JoeyCai That is what I am doing now as shown in my example.  In your link you can see that mysite.azurewebsites.net is displayed on the login page.  I am trying to have that not happen if it is possible.